# How to print y in the case as given below instead of #?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

```
 datatype expr = constant of int 
               |pow of expr * int
               | variable of string
               | product of expr *expr ;
 val x = variable("x");
 fun integ(x,pow(y,a))= if (x=y) then pow(x,a+1) else product(x,pow(y,a));
 integ(x,variable("y"),2);
```

Gives me output
product (variable "x",pow (variable #,2));
I want y instead of # there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables control SML/NJ printing.  Set them higher if you want to see more.

```
Control.Print.printLength := 1000
Control.Print.printDepth := 1000
Control.Print.stringDepth := 1000
```